# Friction as a cause of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, friction, free-body-diagram

[image]

Can anyone help me to understand why friction force is not opposing the resultant centripetal force acting on the box and instead being the cause of its existence?

Comment: Can you rotate the figure. Awkward to view

Comment: There isn't friction and a centripetal force. There is just friction. Since it happens to be acting towards the circle it can be called a centripetal force. Just like you call gravity at the surface of the Earth a downward force.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me to understand why friction force is not opposing
>   the resultant centripetal force acting on the box and instead being
>   the cause of its existence?

In this example, friction *is* the centripetal force.

Think about having an object attached to the end of a string and swinging it in a circle. The tension in the string is the centripetal force acting toward the center to prevent the object from flying off tangentially to the circular path. In the example depicted above, friction force takes the place of the string, therefore

$$f=\frac{MV^2}{r}$$

But in the case of friction, in order to prevent relative motion the magnitude of the friction force must be less the maximum possible static friction force, or

$$f=\frac{MV^2}{r}<μ_{s}mg$$

where $μ_s$ is the coefficient of static friction.

So if the centripetal force exceeds the maximum static friction force, the box will slide and the resisting force is now the kinetic friction force, which is generally less than the static friction force.

It's the same situation as a box on a  passenger seat of a hard cornering car. You make a hard left turn and the box wants to slide towards the passenger side door due to inertia per Newton's first law- *a body in motion tends to stay in motion unless acted upon by an external force.* If the centripetal force does not exceed the maximum static friction force, the box won't slide. Otherwise it will slide opposed only by the kinetic friction force.

> So does the box moves towards origin ( centre ) due to centripetal
>   force?  Or is the inertia which is opposing the friction?

I suppose the answer is yes since because the centripetal force (friction force) causes a centripetal acceleration towards the center that it is constantly changing the direction of motion of the box towards the center.  I think that would be the usual answer.

But I also think it depends on what one means by “moving” towards the center.

Does the centripetal force actually cause the box to move towards the center, that is, cause it to physically travel a path radially to the center thereby decreasing its position (radius) with respect to the center?

To answer that, I think it is instructive that "centripetal" actually means center *seeking*. For object's moving in circular motion, there is a net force (the centripetal force) acting towards the center which causes the object to *seek* the center. THe term "seeking", in turn, is defined as “an attempt or desire top obtain or achieve (something)”. For an interesting discussion see https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-1/The-Centripetal-Force-Requirement

So you might say that while the box is “seeking” to move towards the center, it does not actually move towards the center. It may be a matter of semantics.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Look at (b) of the pic, in the text given below the diagram it was given that three forces are acting on box : weight, normal force and friction. And since the resultant force must act towards the centre as it has acceleration of v^2/r. This implies that friction =mv^2/r. This is what is confusing me

Comment: Shouldn't it be friction-mv^2/r=0 and not directly equal to zero as it was also mentioned that the box is at rest?

Comment: @AtharavKarhad You are right, had my terms (centripetal vs centrifugal) reversed. But the movement of the box and person towards the walls is still due to inertia. It is actually the friction that provides the centripetal force  in lieu of, say, a string attached to the center and the objects. I will correct. Thanks.

Comment: @AtharavKarhad I have revised my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: So does the box moves towards origin ( centre ) due to centripetal force?

Comment: Or is the inertia which is opposing the friction?

Comment: @AtharavKarhad See my additional revisions in response to these comment. Hopefully this will finally remove your doubts.

Comment: @AtharavKarhad I have had some second thoughts. My thinking was that the object is not moving toward the center because, if it did, there would be in my mind a reduction in the radius of the circle. However I do agree that friction is pulling the box in. I have found an explanation of centripetal force that, I think, would satisfy you and I. So I will revise my answer one more time.

Comment: @AtharavKarhad See my latest revised answer to your last questions.